# Drupal database connection error with Docker - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-7

New to Docker and I'm trying to set up as a development environment on a Drupal 7 project. I'm running into this error when I visit `localhost:8080` after running `docker-compose up`:

```
Error

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/includes/lock.inc).
```

It looks like it's having an issue connecting to my database. When I run `docker ps -a` I can see my 2 containers are up and running, so they seem to build just fine. My issue is just connecting my drupal container to the mysql container.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal:7.53-apache
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    links:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.35
    container_name: app_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
```

Am I overlooking something else that would connect the two containers? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to map the correct ports and the php DATABASE_HOST. for me this works:

```
db:
    image: dev/mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
php:
    image: dev/alpine-nginx-php5.6
    environment:
        DATABASE_HOST: db
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./SRC:/var/www/
    links:
        - db
```

but i would suggest to store your database outside of the docker-container. if you have to rebuild or it has a fatal crash everything is deleted.

Comment: @hidace before i forget to ask: did you change your config in settings.php inside of drupal. you have to use the "host" => "db" or in your case "host" => "mysql" + all the credentials